# Reset MediaWiki password without email

Tags: php, mediawiki

We set up a MediaWiki server for organizing docs.One of our customers forget his password.We need to reset the password for him.

In the [MediaWiki docs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords) ,there are three ways to do it:

First is to reset by email. Since we do not have a mail server,we can't done with it.

Second  is using changePassword.php, we try it. But we found other account can be changed successfully,but not this account. After the script runs, the new password is still not working.

Third is using direct database modification,since our version is 1.22. still other account can be changed, but not this account. After update the database,the user cannot login in with new password. sql as foolow:

```
`UPDATE `user` SET user_password = CONCAT(':B:somesalt:', MD5(CONCAT('somesalt-',    MD5('somepass')))) WHERE user_name = 'someuser';`
```

We have no idea why is this happen? Will be MediaWiki bug? Is anyone have a idea?  thanks!

Comment: Is there any error message from `changePassword.php`? What's the difference between these two accounts?

Comment: there is no error in changePassword.php and said the password has been set. I could not found any difference between this account and any other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens for an encryption problem. [I've had this error too](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T58114), on a wiki. Have you tried replacing the password with a very simple one? If that works, try looking into your encryption library (the source of the error can be very subtle at times).